# Can javascript cause 1-2 min delay randomly before displaying a web page?

Tags: javascript, laravel, cookies, browser

Since I added the following javascript in the header of my webpages code as well as used `hisorange/browser-detect` in Laravel, I experienced random delay every 10-15 min before the requested page appears on screen.  After that everything is completely normal for another 10-15 min then it happens again and again...

In Firefox dev tools, there is no network activity... just a long delay.

The purpose of the above is to detect window size and resize and display the correct html code in Laravel blade.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@3.0.5/dist/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var limit = 769;
 var width = $(window).width();
 Cookies.set('windowW',$(window).width(),{ expires:7});
 $(window).resize(function() {
     if ((width > limit && $(window).width() < limit) || (width < limit && $(window).width() > limit)) {
           Cookies.set('windowW',$(window).width(),{ expires:7});
           location.reload();
      }
 });
 </script>
```

For xxx, here is the code I have in AppServiceProvider.php:

```
 use Browser;

 $platform = 'desktop'; $is_mobile = false;
 if (Browser::isMobile()) { $platform = 'mobile'; $is_mobile = true; }
 else if (Browser::isTablet()) { $platform = 'tablet'; $is_mobile = false; }
 if (getCookie('windowW')) { $windowW = getCookie('windowW')[0]; } else { $windowW = 1000; }
```

When I remove the javascript above as well as the use of Browser, I do not get delays anymore.

So my question is ... is there anything wrong in the way I am doing that?  And is it possible that the code above could cause the error?

Comment: Yes, try add it at the end of page, cache it, use CDN or use faster remote source for your JS scripts.

Comment: @EHFShahab the js are all at the bottom of the page (see on my website paulgodard.com).  So my question stands... can the js at the very bottom of the page cause the delay of no network activity for 1-2 min?

Comment: You wrote that you aded js into the header, maybe you should add it to the footer